# string was not recognized as valid Date Time using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have tried every possible solution online but can't figure out why i am still getting this error
"string was not recognized as valid Date Time"
the funny thing is that i am converting 2 date times, one is cell 3 in my gridview and the other one is cell 7 but the Cell 3 works fine and but Cell 7 does not want to convert and both of them are the same data types!!.  I am pulling these data from my sql server table and the data types are varchar but the format should be mm/dd/yyyy.
I have tried this method but it did not work:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {

                DateTime ExpectedSubDate = DateTime.Parse(gr.Cells[3].Text);
                DateTime strTargetDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[7].Text, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have also tried this method but did not work either

```
DateTime strTargetDate = DateTime.Parse(gr.Cells[7].Text);
```

I have also tried this way but did not work either:

```
DateTime strTargetDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[7].Text, "MM/DD/YYYY", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Can you post the example dates, the one in cell 3 that works and the one in cell 7 that doesn't?

Comment: your date format looks to be incorrect.. perhaps you could try something like the following "M/d/yyyy hh:mm"

Comment: in cell 3 i have something like this: 11/05/2012 and in cell 7 i have 11/26/2012 and the data types are the same, pretty much everything is the same..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format string is case sensetive, otherwise it can't know where you want it to parse as months or as minutes.

For a date and time, for example `"11/15/2012 02:26:35 PM"`:

```
DateTime strTargetDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[7].Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For just a date, for example `"11/15/2012"`:

```
DateTime strTargetDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[7].Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Ref: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i have tried this too but still getting the same error

Comment: @moe: I hae tried both with the example strings, and they do work. The likely reason then is that the column doesn't contain the values that you think that they do.

Comment: thanks guys it is working now, i just the contents of my table and created new ones and walaa....

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is incorrect. Format strings are case-sensitive.

mm = Minutes
dd = Days
MM = Months
yyyy = Years

It should be this:

```
CultureInfo usa = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime strTargetDate = DateTime.ParseExact(gr.Cells[7].Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", usa );
```

You could still use InvariantCulture, but the mm/dd/yyyy date format really is unique to the USA.

Comment: thanks but i am still getting the same error i don't know what else to do

Comment: Please edit your question with your updated source code and the full exception report including the original message and full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

look at the examples here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx

a straight string parse is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any hidden columns in your GridView?  If so, your column indices might be off and you might be pulling the wrong data.  Try setting a breakpoint at the failing date parse in your code and checking the value of `gr.Cells[7].Text` in the Immediate window, to make sure you're pulling the right text.

Comment: no i don't but i guess it is working now.  i just deleted the table and inserted new data